# Inter Changing the position of div when window size is changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 div. Actually on full width of window , it is like

[image]

And when the window is re-sized, i got 
[image]

But actually i want the output like
[image]

How i rewrite my css (or any jquery for that) for to get this out put

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>

</div>
.wrap {width: 85%; margin: auto; overflow: hidden;}
 .left {float: right; height: 250px; width: 49%; background: pink;}
   .right {float: left; height: 250px; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 49%;}
   .right {background: green;}
    @media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    .left, .right {float: none; margin-bottom: 5px; height: 200px;}
       }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/deKMy/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/deKMy/2/

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>

</div>


.wrap {width: 85%; margin: auto; overflow: hidden;}
.left {float: left; height: 250px; width: 49%; background: green;}
.right {float: right; height: 250px; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 49%;}
.right {background: pink;}
@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    .left, .right {float: none; margin-bottom: 5px; height: 200px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just swap the two divs:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right top"></div>
</div>

.wrap {width: 85%; margin: auto; overflow: hidden;}
.left {float: right; height: 250px; width: 49%; background: pink;}
.right {float: left; height: 250px; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 49%;}
.right.top {background: green;}
@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    .left, .right {float: none; margin-bottom: 5px; height: 200px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change the .css like this .

```
.wrap {width: 85%; margin: auto; overflow: hidden;}
.left {float: left; height: 250px; width: 49%; background: pink;}
.right {float: right; height: 250px; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 49%;}
.right.top {background: green;}
@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    .left, .right {float: none; margin-bottom: 5px; height: 200px;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ayiem999/XgLC5/